# Submersions are Imbeddings

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

In the page 80 of the book - Varadarajan, V.S. Lie Groups, Lie Algebras and Their Representations the author affirm that one-to-one submersions are imbeddings.

I would like to know how I could prove this.

Comment: Oh, this is just the invariance of domain theorem. Incidentally, it is "embedding" (but "immersion").

Comment: Is there any direct way to prove it?

Comment: Yes, Invariance of Domain is quite easy for smooth maps, it is just a corollary of the inverse function theorem.

Comment: I have that $f:M^m\rightarrow N^n$  is a submersion. Then, $d(f)_p$ is surjective for all $p \in M$ and $m \geq n$. The Inverse Function Theorem only applies between manifolds with the same dimension, unless I look over the image $f(M)$.

Comment: Injective submersion implies equality of dimensions (unless your domain is empty).

Comment: Thank you so much! This solves the problem.

Comment: You can either delete the question or write and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Hi @Victor Hugo and @Moishe Cohen, wait for me, I still don't understand, just curious. I don't have enough 50 reputations, so I am not able to comment. So, $f:M^m \to N^n, m \ge n$ is a submersion, so $\text{rank } (d_pf) = n$ for all $p \in M$. Because $d_p f$ is a linear map, we have $$\text{dim } Ker(d_p (f)) = \text{dim }T(M) - \text{rank } d_p(f) = m - n.$$ But we only have $f$ is one-to-one, i.e., $f$ is injective, not $d_p (f)$.  So, how can I know $m=n$? Thanks.

Comment: By the Invariance Of Domain Theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain, $f:M \rightarrow N$ is a open map. By the Brouwer Theorem, about dimension of the homeomorphic sets, we have that $dim f(M)=dim(M)$. Hence, by the Inverse function Theorem, $f$ is a local difeomorphism. Since that injective local difeomorphism are global difeomorphism, we have that $f$ is a immersion. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Okay, merci, I'm reading the link. And also, good night.