# Does a bijective submersion imply diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Submersion, by definition is, $df_x: T_x(X)\rightarrow T_y(Y)$ is surjective and if it is also bijective, then intuitively it is a diffeomorphism for me as $df_x^{-1}:T_y(Y)\rightarrow T_x(X)$ is well defined. Am I correct? Thanks and appreciate a hint.

Comment: Only locally. For example, $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow S^1, x\mapsto \exp(ix)$ is a submersion, its derivative $df_x$ is invertible for every $x\in \mathbb R$ but $f$ is not a global diffeomorphism.

Comment: I see, thanks. I am confused as to how $df_x$ is invertible for your example. $df_x = -sinx+icosx$ and for $x=x_0$ and $x=x_0+2\pi$, $df_x$ has the same value? So it is not bijective?

Comment: Well, the problem is on $f$ and not its derivative. A diffeomorphism $f$ is a smooth bijective map whose inverse $f^{-1}$ is also smooth. In my example, $f$ is not injective thus not bijective, that's all. We usually say that $f$ is a local diffeomorphism meaning that around each point, the restriction of $f$ defines a diffeomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes. [Injective (smooth) submersions are (smooth) embeddings.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2344307/submersions-are-imbeddings) Therefore, bijective submersions are surjective embeddings, also known as diffeomorphisms.
2. If $f$ is a bijective submersion, then we don't have *right away* that $df_{x}$ has an inverse. The given bijection is $f$ not $df_{x}$. Of course however, diffeomorphisms $g$ are both submersions and immersions, and thus $dg_{x}$ is invertible (i.e. both a submersion and immersion).

Answer (score 1):

Your **claim** follows from the *Global Rank theorem*  which says that if $F:M \rightarrow N$ is a smooth map of constant rank then the following holds true:

1. If $F$ is injective then $F$ is an immersion.
2. If $F$ is surjective then $F$ is a submersion.
3. If $F$ is bijective then $F$ is a diffeomorphism.

Now in particular (3) follows from (1) and (2) in a straightforward way as follows:

It is a known result that if $F$ is both an immersion and submersion then $F$ is a Local Diffeomeorphism.
So your **claim** follows from the fact that every bijective local diffeomorphism is a diffeomorphism and submersions are by definition smooth maps of constant rank.

For the detailed proof of all the above stated facts please check out **Theorem 4.14 (Global Rank Theorem)**, **Pg-83**, *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, *John M. Lee, 2nd Edition*.