# Why inner variations are diffeomorphisms?

Tags: differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, calculus-of-variations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ be an open, bounded, connected domain with smooth boundary.

Let $\eta \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a smooth compactly supported $n$-tuple of real valued functions.

Define $\phi(x)=x+\epsilon\, \eta(x)$.

How to prove that for sufficiently small $\epsilon$, $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism $\Omega \to \Omega$?

I can see why $\phi(\Omega)\subseteq \Omega$ for small $\epsilon$, but I don't see why $\phi|_{\Omega}$ is injective, or why $\phi(\Omega)\supseteq \Omega$. I **do** see why $d\phi$ is invertible for small $\epsilon$.

**Edit:**

Here is some progress: (Is there a more elementary way, which do not use the fact the Jacobian is null-Lagrangian?).

Assume $\phi$ is injective (see comment below).

First, we have
$$
\phi(\bar \Omega) \subseteq \overline{\phi( \Omega)} \subseteq \bar \Omega.
$$

The injectivity of $\phi$ implies
$$
\text{Vol}(\phi(\bar \Omega))=\int_{\bar \Omega} J\phi\stackrel{(1)}{=}\int_{\bar \Omega} \text{Id}=\text{Vol}(\bar \Omega),
$$
where equality $(1)$ follows, since the Jacobian is null-Lagrangian.

Thus, we have
$$
\phi(\bar \Omega) \subseteq \bar \Omega, \,\,\, \text{Vol}(\phi(\bar \Omega))=\text{Vol}(\bar \Omega).
$$

This implies that $\phi(\bar \Omega)=\bar \Omega$. Thus, $\phi:\bar \Omega \to \bar \Omega$ is bijective, hence by the inverse function theorem, it is a diffeomorphism.

**Is there a direct way to see $\phi:\bar \Omega \to \bar \Omega$ is surjective?**

Comment: Injectivity follows from the fact that $\eta$ is Lipschitz, say with constant $k$. As $\phi(x)=\phi(y) \implies x-y = \varepsilon(\eta(y)-\eta(x))$, and it follows that $\|x-y\| \leqslant k\varepsilon \|x-y\|$. For $\varepsilon$ small enough (in fact, $\varepsilon < 1/k$), we then have $x=y$.

Comment: Thanks! That is a great observation! I wonder whether there is a simple direct argument for the surjectivity.

Comment: I was thinking about proving it first on $\mathbb{R}^n$. It is clearly injective for small $\varepsilon$. For the surjectivity, I would say that the image is open (implicit function theorem, since the gradient is everywhere invertible) and closed (I still have to think about why). Then it is the identity on the complement of $\Omega$ if $\varepsilon \cdot \|\eta\|_\infty$ is less than the distance between the support of $\eta$ and the border of $\Omega$, so it must map $\Omega$ to itself, and I guess that being a diffeomorphism on $\Omega$ follows from this.

Comment: Yes, an open-close argument is the clue (hence the connected hypothesis)

Comment: I have summed up my answer as an answer. Actually, I don't think I have used the connectedness of $\Omega$ in my argument, but just that of $\mathbb{R}^n$. But maybe I have cheated somewhere

Comment: @Didier, to me it seems the only hypothesis that I have used is that $\Omega$ is open. But I would not be surprised to be wrong XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if we prove that $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism on $\mathbb{R}^n$, we are done, since it maps the complement of $\Omega$ and of $\bar\Omega$ in themselves.

As you and previous comments suggest, injectivity follows for small $\varepsilon$ as well as the invertibility of the differential. This actually holds in the whole $\mathbb{R}$.

To prove surjectivity, we just need to show that the image is open and closed (and non-void) since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is connected.

The openness of $\phi(\mathbb{R}^n)$ follows from the inverse function theorem, as for a given point $x$ of the image, the gradient calculated in its preimage is invertible (thus exists a whole neighborhood of $x$ that is in the image).

The closure follows by a compactness argument: Assume $x_n$ is a sequence of vectors in the image of $\phi$ that converges to $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, the preimage of the subsequence (let's call it $y_n$) is bounded. Taking a convergent subsequence $y_{n_k}\to y$, by the continuity of $\phi$, we must have $\phi(y)=x$.

I guess there are some theorems concerning bijections whose gradient is everywhere surjective, but I am not an expert in that.

Comment: In the last line I was thinking about something like this:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2344307/submersions-are-imbeddings

Comment: Thanks. How do you see that $\phi(\Omega^c) \subseteq \Omega^c$?

Comment: I would say that the function $\eta$ is identically $0$ outside $\Omega$. So, the function $\phi$ restricted to $\Omega^c$ is just the identity.